# How to install Gnome Shell  latest version in Offline-mode?

Tags: installation, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

I can't using

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

Because, My Internet connection is very slow, So I want to download the packages first and copy them to my Laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had many friends' computer where I required to install Ubuntu as well essential post-install tasks (like installing required Packages for playing restricted media formats, GNOME Shell, etc.) What I do is as follows:

### Get the Packages

- Get to a computer where there's a decent internet connection, and boot from Ubuntu LiveCD or Bootable Flash Drive.
- Firstly, **update the package repositories** (from Update Manager by clicking "**Check**", which updates entire package cache).
- Then install **Synaptic** from Software Center.
- And now the real work starts from Synaptic.
- Open Synaptic and first hit "**Reload**", when its done, click "**Mark All Upgrades**" and then hit "**Apply**", this will bring a dialog that shows packages to be updated, below that is a **checkbox** that says "**Download Package Files Only**".

[image: Package Installation Confirmation Dialog]

- Just **mark that checkbox** so it'll not install anything and just download the packages and keep it in the cache.
- When its done, install other packages that you'll need, like `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, `vlc`, `gnome-shell`, etc.
- Mark the mentioned packages (it'll also mark required dependencies) just **DON'T forget to check that "Download Package Files Only" option**, when you click apply after marking all the packages.
- The reason why we're ONLY downloading the packages instead of installing is pretty simple that we don't wanna install anything in the Live session of Ubuntu.
- Once, download of all the packages is done, open `nautilus` (i.e. file manager) and navigate to `/var/cache/apt/archives`.
- You'll see here all the packages that you downloaded using Synaptic, along with two other things, a file `lock` and a folder `partial`.
- Just copy all the `.deb` files from that location ignoring that `lock` file and `partial` folder.
- And paste the packages in some other partition or a flash drive where you can keep it for later use.
- What we did in above steps is **downloaded the packages for the updates for Ubuntu released so-far, and the apps that we need** after installing Ubuntu on our target machine.

### Installing the Packages

- Now that we have all the required packages, install Ubuntu.
- Please note that though we have all the packages downloaded, **we still need an internet connection on a target machine** (its absolutely fine if the connection is slow as we'll not be needing faster connection now).
- Once, installation is done and you login to Ubuntu Desktop, open Nautilus as root by running `gksu nautilus`, and then navigate again to `/var/cache/apt/archives`.
- Now, **paste all the packages here** which we downloaded earlier in live Ubuntu session, and close Nautilus.
- Again, **update the package repositories** using Update Manager as mentioned above in very 2nd point. (this is the task why we need internet connection, but, updating package cache shouldn't take long even on computer with slow internet connection)
- Now you'll see list of available updates in the Update Manager, but also, you'll see a notice below the list that says "**updates already downloaded**". You can now safely install Updates and it won't download anything now.
- Similarly, you can open Software Center and install the packages which you downloaded earlier, and none of them will require to download anything further.
- This is how you can save bandwidth as well as install the packages which are already downloaded.

**Note:** There are other ways too which can be used to install packages offline, like using [APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/) or running `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` in a folder where downloaded packages exist, but I don't know why but I don't like APTonCD and the send option often causes dependency issues or in worst cases, broken installation.

Also, note that it may happen that you need internet connection while installing the package from Synaptic, but with this method, the need to download anything during installation will be negligible.

I know this is pretty long list of instructions, but believe me once you get used to it (I do this at every release of Ubuntu to install it on computers with limited internet connection) it is fairly easier. And also, it doesn't require any 3rd-party app to perform the task and you'll also learn something while doing this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Download from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gnome-shell/3.4/gnome-shell-3.4.1.tar.xz or ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gnome-shell/3.4/gnome-shell-3.4.1.tar.xz

Ensure you have the required dependencies (evolution-data-server-3.4.2, Folks-0.6.9, gcr-3.4.1, gjs-1.32.0, gnome-menus-3.4.2, gnome-settings-daemon-3.4.2, JSON-GLib-0.14.2, libcroco-0.6.5, libgnome-keyring-3.4.1, Mutter-3.4.1, NetworkManager-0.9.4.0 and telepathy-logger-0.4.0).

```
./configure --prefix=/usr \
        --sysconfdir=/etc \
        --libexecdir=/usr/lib/gnome-shell \
        --with-ca-certificates=/etc/ssl/ca-bundle.crt &&
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: is there any package that include those dependencies ? I need an instant way. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the above method or use the following command to get the download links for the required packages. (**apt-get --print-uris**)

```
sudo apt-get --print-uris install gnome-shell
```

Then download the packages from a hi speed Internet connection and install.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it and any further updates using [keryx](http://keryxproject.org/). Download the portable version.

The keryx executable is inside the `bin` folder.

**Step 1: Let keryx know your computer**

Download it,extract it to computer with low speed. There will be one button to create a profile. Create the profile. Copy keryx folder to USB drive.

**Step 2: Download packages from other computer**

Now take the folder to computer with good internet access. This client can be of any OS. (Windows also but you need python). Open `keryx` and then select profile created in step 1. Click on `Manage`. Now it will download the source files as listed in your previous computer. Once completed, you can search for any package in the search box and choose to download. (In this case gnome-shell and its dependencies )

**Step3: Install in your computer**

Copy back the folder to your computer. Again run `Keryx`, Now select  `Project > Install` to install the packages.

Comment: i can really understand, sorry -can you explain it ?

Comment: updated my answer. Take a look, I m sorry can't add screen shot now.:( Will update later.